# Looping through Multiple pages while scraping with python

Tags: python, parsing, dataframe, web, web-scraping

I am trying to parse multiple page on IDMb. The parser is stuck on gathering information from one page. I have tried many forums to solve this to no avail. I suspect it has something to do with not setting up my embedded loop correctly or my initial request. Please help. Thanks.

## Problems with this script: Loops on one page.

```
#Basic libraries

from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from random import randint

#More advanced libraries
from time import sleep
from time import time
from IPython.core.display import clear_output
from warnings import warn

base_url = 'http://www.imdb.com/search/title?release_date=2000,2017&sort=num_votes,desc&page='
response = get(base_url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

#data lists to append

names           = []
years           = []
imdb_ratings    = []
metascores      = []
votes           = []

#preparing the monitoring loop

pages =  str(range(1,5))

start_time = time()
requests = 0

#for every page in the interval 1-4
for page in pages:

#make a get request
    response = get(base_url + page)

#pause the loop
    sleep(randint(8,15))

#Monitor the requests
    requests += 1
    elapsed_time = time() - start_time
    if requests > 4:
        warn:('Number of requests was greater than expected.')
        break

    elif response.status_code != 200:
        warn('Request: {}; Frequency: {} requests/s'.format(requests, response.status_code))

    else:
        print('Request: {}; Frequency: {} requests/s'.format(requests, requests/elapsed_time))
        clear_output(wait = True)

    page_html = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')  

#root
    movie_containers = soup.find_all('div', class_= 'lister-item mode-advanced')

#looping through containers
for container in movie_containers:
    if container.find('div', class_ = 'ratings-metascore') is not None:

        #The name
        name = container.h3.a.text
        #print(name)
        names.append(name)

        #The Year
        year = container.find('span', class_ = 'lister-item-year').text
        #print(year)
        years.append(year)

        #IDMb rating             
        imdb = container.strong.text
        #print(imdb)
        imdb_ratings.append(imdb)

        #Metascore              
        metascore = container.find('span', class_= 'metascore').text
        #print(metascore)
        metascores.append(int(metascore))

        #Number of Votes
        vote = container.find('span', attrs = {'name':'nv'})['data-value']
        #print(vote)
        votes.append(int(vote))


#keeping track of data        
test_df= pd.DataFrame({'Movie': names,
                        'Year': years,
                        'IMDb': imdb_ratings,
                        'Metascore': metascores,
                        'Votes': votes})
print(test_df.info())
test_df
```

`

Comment: You know that there is a python api for `IMDB`?

Comment: Btw your code doesn't work, or you didn't put the full source.\

Comment: Your code had some issues as well, i've corrected those

Comment: I do know there is an API for IMDb but I am practicing my web scraping.

Comment: I apologize I meant to write, for page in pages

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1:**
What you could do is, anytime you collect your data on that page and you are done, go to the next page by changing the urls `page` value to +1.

```
http://www.imdb.com/search/title?
release_date=2000,2017&sort=num_votes,desc&page=2&ref_=adv_nxt
```

**Solution 2:** You can get the same behavior by clicking the `next` url at the bottom of the page. To do that, you have to scroll down to the bottom of the page.

Here is your corrected code, which outputs at the end a `test.csv`

```
#Basic libraries

from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from random import randint

#More advanced libraries
from time import sleep
from time import time
from IPython.core.display import clear_output
from warnings import warn

base_url = 'http://www.imdb.com/search/title?release_date=2000,2017&sort=num_votes,desc&page='
response = get(base_url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

#data lists to append

names           = []
years           = []
imdb_ratings    = []
metascores      = []
votes           = []

#preparing the monitoring loop

pages =  str(range(1,5))

start_time = time()
requests = 0

#for every page in the interval 1-4
urls = [base_url+str(x) for x in range(0,10)]
for url in urls:

#make a get request
    response = get(url)

#pause the loop
    sleep(randint(2,3))

#Monitor the requests
    requests += 1
    elapsed_time = time() - start_time
    if requests > 4:
        warn('Number of requests was greater than expected.')
        break

    elif response.status_code != 200:
        warn('Request: {}; Frequency: {} requests/s'.format(requests, response.status_code))

    else:
        print('Request: {}; Frequency: {} requests/s'.format(requests, requests/elapsed_time))
        clear_output(wait = True)

    page_html = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')  

#root
    movie_containers = soup.find_all('div', class_= 'lister-item mode-advanced')

    #looping through containers
    for container in movie_containers:
        if container.find('div', class_ = 'ratings-metascore') is not None:

            #The name
            name = container.h3.a.text
            #print(name)
            names.append(name)

            #The Year
            year = container.find('span', class_ = 'lister-item-year').text
            #print(year)
            years.append(year)

            #IDMb rating             
            imdb = container.strong.text
            #print(imdb)
            imdb_ratings.append(imdb)

            #Metascore              
            metascore = container.find('span', class_= 'metascore').text
            #print(metascore)
            metascores.append(int(metascore))

            #Number of Votes
            vote = container.find('span', attrs = {'name':'nv'})['data-value']
            #print(vote)
            votes.append(int(vote))


#keeping track of data        
test_df= pd.DataFrame({'Movie': names,
                        'Year': years,
                        'IMDb': imdb_ratings,
                        'Metascore': metascores,
                        'Votes': votes})
print(test_df.info())
test_df.to_csv("test.csv", sep=",", encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help. I tried out your code and a couple of things happened that don't get me all the way to my goal. 
1. All of the data comes out into one column in the csv file (which wouldn't be a problem if the data was seperated by commas)
2. The movies repeat which was my initial problem

Comment: problem is the line after comment `#root` instead of the object `soup` you should call `page_html`, because `soup` is defined outside of the for loop.

Answer (score -1):

I figure it out. You just have to add page+=1 at the end of the loop and add commas to the end of each data entry:

```
pages = 1
ranger = range(1,4)
requests = 0

for n in ranger:

#make a get request

    response = get(base_url + str(pages))

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

#pause the loop
    sleep(randint(2,3))

#Monitor the requests
    requests += 1
    elapsed_time = time() - start_time
    if requests > 4:
       warn('Number of requests was greater than expected.')
       break

    if response.status_code != 200:
        warn('Request: {}; Frequency: {} requests/s'.format(requests, response.status_code))

    else:
        print('Request: {}; Frequency: {} requests/s'.format(requests, requests/elapsed_time))
        clear_output(wait = True) 

#root
    movie_containers = soup.find_all('div', class_= 'lister-item mode-advanced')

#looping through containers
    for container in movie_containers:
        if container.find('div', class_ = 'ratings-metascore') is not None:

        #The name
            name = container.h3.a.text
        #print(name)
            names.append(name + ',')

        #The Year
            year = container.find('span', class_ = 'lister-item-year').text
            years.append(year + ',')

        #IDMb rating             
            imdb = container.strong.text
        #print(imdb)
            imdb_ratings.append(imdb + ',')

        #Metascore              
            metascore = container.find('span', class_= 'metascore').text
            metascores.append(metascore + ',')

        #Number of Votes
            vote = container.find('span', attrs = {'name':'nv'})['data-value']
            votes.append(vote + ',')

    pages += 1
```